# Including plotly graphs in pdf report using Shiny Rmarkdown on Centos7/linux

Tags: r, linux, pdf, r-markdown, plotly

I'm trying to create a pdf report using R, Shiny, and Rmarkdown on a Centos7/linux server that would include both plotly generated plots and tables using kable.

I've been able to successfully generate pdf reports on a Mac OS however, when I move the code to the linux based server I run into issues with generating the pdf report through the web browser. I've listed the error message I receive while generating the report below

The corresponding error I receive is:

---

pandoc: Could not find image `/srv/shiny-server/.../figure-latex/raw%20variant%20plot-1.pdf', skipping...

pandoc: Could not find image `/srv/shiny-server/.../figure-latex/Variant%20Table-1.pdf', skipping...

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.

! LaTeX Error: File `titling.sty' not found.

---

I've tried a number of different solutions to resolve this problem including updating my Latex postscript editor to the most recent version Texlive2017 (that contains the 'titling.sty', and tested to see if it can generate pdfs when launched within the linux server envrionment), updating Rstudio/Rmarkdown from the github repository, updating R to the most recent version (3.3) and all associated R plot/other packages.

I suspect that the issue is that Rmarkdown isn't pointing to my Texlive within the linux environment so that it doesn't recognize the titling.sty package.

I've also tried using the downloadHandler as provided by Shiny however ran into similar issues. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

I've included my code below:

server.R

---

```
    generateReport <- observeEvent(input$genReportInput, {

    params <- list(runId = as.list(input$runInput),
            data_Specimen =  sumSpecimenTab(),
            rawdata_VariantPlotRun = runIdQMData(),
            rawdata_VariantPlotAll = allRunQMData())

        outputPath <- paste("qmPath/", Sys.Date(), "_QMrun_nsc", input$runInput, ".pdf", sep = "")


        rmarkdown::render("test_downloadQMReport.Rmd", output_dir = qmPath, output_file = paste(Sys.Date(), "_QMrun_nsc", input$runInput, ".pdf", sep = ""),
                  pdf_document(latex_engine = "pdflatex", latex_dependency("") ), params = params,envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    })
```

---

Rmarkdown

---

````
---
output: pdf_document
always_allow_html: yes
params:
  data_Specimen: NA
  rawdata_VariantPlotRun: NA
  rawdata_VariantPlotAll: NA
---



```{r libraries, echo = FALSE}
library(plotly)
library(lazyeval)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(knitr)
library(pander)
library(gtable)
```

```{r kable table, echo=FALSE}

kable(sumSpecimenTab <- tbl_df(params$data_Specimen))

```

```{r raw variant plot, plotly=TRUE, fig.height=9, fig.width=8, echo=FALSE}

runInputQMData <- tbl_df(params$rawdata_VariantPlotRun)
allRunQMdf <- tbl_df(params$rawdata_VariantPlotAll)
maxVF <- max(allRunQMdf$VF) + 0.1

ggplot(runInputQMData, aes(x=interaction(cDNAChange, GI), y=VF, color = GI, label = Rep)) + ylim(0,maxVF) + geom_point(shape=16, size=2) + labs(title= "")  + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,3.5,1), "cm")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=70, hjust=1, size = 10), axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(), legend.position="none", text=element_text(size=12))

```
````